# Django admin add custom button in change form depending on a form field value

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I have an application that overrides het Django change form. What I want to change is the submit buttons on the bottom. Underneath is `change_form.html` in a django app:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %} 
    ## add some buttons
{% endblock %}
```

The button I want to show/add depends on the value of a certain field in the form names 'status'. How can I get the value of a field in the template... **something like**:

```
{% if form.field.status == 'unresolved' %}
    <input type="submit" value="Mark as resolved" class="default" name="_save" />
{% endif %}
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm not getting any errors. There is simply nothing displayed.

Looping through var 'adminform' will get me to the field I need

```
{% for fieldset in adminform %}
    {% for line in fieldset %}
        {% for field in line %}
            {% if field.field.name == 'status' %}
                this is status {{ field.field.name }} - {{ field.contents }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I want to access it directly. **Something like:**

```
{% if adminform.0.0.field.status == 'unresolved' %}
    <input type="submit" value="Mark as resolved" class="default" name="_save" />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code you've got? What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. There is simply nothing displayed. see my update

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
{% if adminform.form.status.value == 'unresolved' %}
```

or if the field is readonly, there's another way:

```
{% if adminform.form.instance.status == 'unresolved' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `if` statement to -

```
{% if adminform.status.value == 'unresolved' %}
```

I'm guessing, but I think the `adminform` variable is probably just a form. Have a look at [this section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) to see the atributes of the form fields.

Comment: What does {{ adminform }}, {{ adminform.status }} or {{ adminform.status.value }} output ?